# Excel Conditional Formatting on rows with the same value

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Due to my inability to put my question into a google search which will give me a hint towards the solution I need. I am hoping to find my answer here.

Currently I'm working on a list of articles which are being produced by our factory:
[image]

For the sake of simplicity I'm showing an example. The actual list is several thousands of rows big. This list contains the number of conflicts on an operation of those articles.

The current conditional formatting turns the row with 1 or more conflicts red, but we want to highlight every row of the same article.
Like this goal example, which I've done by hand:
[image]

Is there any way this could be achieved in excel or even visual basic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a MAXIFS conditional format rule. The MAXIFS will determine which articles have conflicts (ie, which articles have at least one value not zero).

Highlight your range (A2:C12) and input the following conditional format rule:

```
=MAXIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$A2)<>0
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I've been looking for.